# Самый быстрый способ записи текста в файл с использованием C# в ОС Linux?

Tags: c#, linux

Какой способ из доступных в .NET в Linux для добавления текста в файл самый быстрый?

Comment: Они все работают с одинаковой скоростью. Узкое место при записи в файл - это жесткий диск.

Comment: Не запаривайтесь - `File.AppendAllText()` или `await File.AppendAllTextAsync()`

Comment: Что в вашем понимании `самый быстрый`? Если быстрый в плане освобождения задачи - используйте асинхронную запись с кешированием. Если быстрый в плане физической записи - как уже выше написали `AppendAllText`. У всех способов свои назначения, плюсы и минусы.

Comment: Имеется в виду самая производительная запись данных на диск.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Вам уже сказали где узкое место при записи данных. Какой способ использования записи данных предпочтителен - зависит от вашего контекста.

Comment: Уточните задачу: вам нужно писать гигабайты или даже терабайты текста в нагруженном приложении или просто вы пока не знакомы с платформой .NET? Если последнее, мы накидаем ссылок на документацию, если первое, то я могу написать и про предварительное выделение места на жёстком диске (что избавит от лишних перемещений головки), и про нюансы использования кодировок (что избавит от лишних перекодирований текста), и про асинхронность (что позволит писать текст в файл, продолжая вычисления) и пр.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

StreamWriter будет быстрее чем File.AppendAllText(), т.к. AppendAllText вызывает InternalAppendAllText.

```
private static void InternalAppendAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
        {
            Contract.Requires(path != null);
            Contract.Requires(encoding != null);
            Contract.Requires(path.Length > 0);
 
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true, encoding))
                sw.Write(contents);
        }
```

Ещё быстрее будет если вы будете писать напрямую массив байт (полученный из текста) через `FileStream WriteAsync`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128951/discussion-on-answer-by-blackmeser---------).